# Insert data into couchdb using angularjs

Tags: angularjs, html, couchdb

I'm new to AngularJs. How to save data from Api into couchdb using AngularJs and retrieve it back. Can anyone give example coding.

Answer (score 1):

'Cause [CouchDB](http://docs.couchdb.org/en/latest/api/) has a REST interface you can use these AngularJS services to access its functionalities:

- [$resource](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngResource/service/$resource)
- [$http](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http)

Eventually here is a tutorial with a step-by-step example:

http://thewebhacker.com/rapid-app-prototyping-with-angularjs-and-couchdb/

Answer (score 0):

Refer this dummy code, this will basically calls URL defined by Couch and returns JSON data,

```
function getItems () {
  $http.get(appSettings.db + '/_design/expenses/_view/byName')
    .success(function (data) {
      $scope.items = data.rows;
    });
}
getItems();
```

For more info, plz refer this link:
http://www.sitepoint.com/tracking-expenses-couchdb-angular/